# I have accidentally unstaged all the changes in my branch using git reset. How to revert it?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-reset

I used git reset without any arguments and even after I committed all the changes after, the changes are still unstaged. How to revert it?

I have made many changes and committed and pushed them to the remote branch. But everytime I try to merge the branch to another branch, I can see the changes are still unstaged.

I was just trying to go back one commit

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you edit your question to explain what you mean with : "But everytime I try to merge the branch to another branch, I can see the changes are still unstaged" ? for example, what commands do you run ? what do they output ?

Comment: I have just created a pull request from my branch to another one and when I try to see the difference between those branches all the classes are showing up even the classes that are common in both the branches. Does that not mean the git reset I have done unstaged all the classes in the branch?

Comment: What do you mean by "go back one commit"?  If you did a reset, it does not change your working directory at all.  You cannot revert, because no commit was made.  If you have changes that are unstaged and you want to discard them, do `git stash`.  That is an operation that can be reversed.  (Be careful when using words like "revert" or "reset", as they have specific meaning in git).  You could also do *WARNING MAY DELETE DATA* `git reset --hard`, but be careful as that operation is not reversible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.